# Powershell Script to import file into a file choose file button

Tags: powershell, import

I am trying to automate a daily import that I need to do from a website.
One server is generating a file to a network drive and I would like to go to the website log with specific credentials and then click on the button to output the file from this network drive.

I can log into the website go to the correct page etc. But I am struggling when I need to click on "choose file" and select it within the script.
Is there a way to do it with PowerShell?

[image: Website Example]

The path would be always the same so there is no input in the script.
The network path would be something like
`S:\Projects\Link\Uploads\Scheduled_Extracts`

The code from the website is : [Website Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5wtX.png)

I am not sure what is relevant for you to help me I was thinking to use : 
typedef enum ShellSpecialFolderConstants

But not really sure on how.

My code so far looks like this :

```
$username = Read-Host " Please Enter your email address "

$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString " Please Enter your pasword " 

$password = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password)) # translate encrypt password

$ie.Navigate("Website.com")

While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('username')
$usernamefield.value = "$username"

$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('password')
$passwordfield.value = "$password"

$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('_submit')
$Link.click()

Start-Sleep -Seconds 3

$ie.Navigate("Website.com\revelantpPage")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3

$typefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('import_form_type')
$typefield.value = "2"

# selection of the file
```

Sorry I am really a beginner in powershell

Comment: You need to show some effort and code before community can help you. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How is the "choose file"-Button implemented? Show us some code. Sometimes you can add a standard value.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the comments I added some info.

Comment: Any Help on this ?